# server log problem

Tags: linux, syslog

I have a linux server running Debain. My logs are not updated in my var/log/messages.
Deamon syslogd is running. Below are the logs are updated in my var/log/messages.

```
Apr xx 20:40:24 xxxxx -- MARK --
Apr 16 22:40:26 xxxxx -- MARK --
Apr 16 23:00:26 xxxxx -- MARK --
```

xxxxx replaced with server hostname.

Can anybody help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: Are you sure you should be seeing anything apart from the MARKs? What services do you expect to see logging? Most of the services on Debian should log to their own logfiles or to /var/log/daemon.log, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try `logger -p user.notice -t test one two three`

Then `sudo tail /var/log/messages`

Update your answer by posting the output of `grep -v ^# /etc/syslog.conf`

Answer (score 0):

```
# grep -v ^# /etc/syslog.conf


auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                                          -/opt/psa/var/log/maillog
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log
uucp.*                          /var/log/uucp.log

mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice

*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

*.emerg                         *


daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.crit;news.err;news.notice;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```